# Does MongoDB Mobile build on top of SQLite?

Tags: android, mongodb, mobile

I can't remember where I've read this, or maybe it was related to CouchDB, but is MongoDB Mobile a native C++ library without any relation to SQLite, or does it effectively store the data in SQLite and provide a layer which makes the behavior MongoDB-like?

I'm asking because I need very high performance. I'm currently using https://github.com/requery/sqlite-android with the JSON1 extension in order to query JSON data, and if MongoDB Mobile would do this without SQLite and offer better performance, I'd switch.

Comment: As one of the people who worked on MongoDB Mobile, I can confirm that it does in fact use SQLite, per your answer below.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Comparing MongoDB and MongoDB Mobile](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/mongodb/mobile/mobile-features/) the following applies:

> Storage Engine Configuration
>
> MongoDB Mobile uses SQLite as a simple
>   key-value store behind the scenes due to its stability and prevalence
>   on devices. MongoDB Mobile does not provide the ability to configure
>   the underlying SQLite deployment or use other storage engines.